# Permission denied for git clone

Tags: windows, git, permissions, clone

I have been trying for two days to clone different repos from the internet into my machine.

The error I get is always:

> Cloning into 'python-docs-hello-world'...
>
> C:/Users/dream/Desktop/KhameleonPython/python-docs-hello-world/.git:
>   Permission denied Deletion of directory
>   'python-docs-hello-world/.git' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)

It is not a problem with the public key as I have found many other answers referencing. I have tried modifying the user permissions to full control from the KhameleonPython empty folder from Properties>Security, to no avail. I have accessed Component Services to give git full permission only not to find git among the local services listed there.

My git is installed in the F: drive and my file is under C:, could that be a problem? I have previously had this problem with other programs such as Node.js npm (init did't work with error EPERM) or atom wouldn't let me create new files in a folder from inside the text editor. Usually a reinstallation solved things but now it didn't. I run Microsoft Windows 10 Home Edition x64.

Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: It seems like a folder called `.git` already exists at this location. Try deleting it maybe? Note that the `.git` folder is usually hidden.

Comment: It was never there, it just gets created when i clone. For some reason it tries to delete it afterwards

Comment: How can I better promote this question?

Comment: The same problem arises when i try to add to a repo: 
git remote add azure https://notebookforever.scm.azurewebsites.net/NotebookForever.git
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
fatal: could not set 'remote.azure.url' to 'https://notebookforever.scm.azurewebsites.net/NotebookForever.git'

Comment: Are you doing this as an administrator?

Comment: running the command as administrator or not, it made no difference

Comment: I cannot live with this anymore, third day in a row.

Comment: Disable your anti-malware product. Alternatively, remove the malware you have installed.

Comment: Is this a malware problem?

Comment: Bitdefender says i'm ok at the last scan. This is a problem I've been having for a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have bitdefender, like I do, I had to allow git to make changes to the HDD by going into BitDefender > Application Access. After I allowed that connection, it worked just fine.